# Block spam using microsoft graph api

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to use the Microsoft graph api to block spam or add emails to the whitelist? I am currently using Microsoft Graph Api powershell and its SUPER FAST. I LOVE IT!

There is a way to add spam to the blacklist using Exchange online powershelling using the `Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-hostedcontentfilterpolicy?view=exchange-ps  command using exchange online powershell. But it not at as fast as the Microsoft Graph API.

If anyone has any ideas let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your question and I'm glad you are enjoying the MS Graph experience on Powershell. To my knowledge, there isn't currently a way to modify spam filter policies using MS Graph - I would recommend working with the ExchangePowerShell cmdlet. Alternatively, would you consider filing a feature request on the [M365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform), so that this can be looked into ?

Let me know if this helps, and if you have further questions.